# Move-Item and preserve filename casing

Tags: powershell

I have file with 2 uppercases in the name and want to move that to another directory, e.g.

```
PS> Move-Item C:\From\FileName.mdf -Destination C:\To\ -Force
```

This however results in losing the uppercases in the filename in the destination.
After the move the filename is: `C:\From\filename.mdf`

How to preserve the casing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. On my Windows 10 system everything works as expected (uppercase stays uppercase). On which OS are you experiencing this behavior?

Comment: In Docker for Windows using `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019`

Comment: Is your host Windows or Linux? Windows filesystems are case insensitive. It might be an odd behavior for core and/or core within Docker. Are From or To on a data volume?

Comment: Host is Windows, and `From` is a data volume.

Answer (score 0):

like that?

```
PS U:\> Move-Item C:\Temp\FileName.mdf -Destination C:\Temp\new\ -Force
PS U:\> dir C:\Temp\new\


    Verzeichnis: C:\Temp\new


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       30.01.2019     10:49              0 FileName.mdf


PS U:\>
```

For me it works.